# Complexity Sorting a finite set of numbers from 0,..,N

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

I have a set of elements $x_1,...,x_N$, they take values $x_i \in \{0,...,N\}  $ for all $i \in \{1,...,N\}$; I need to sort them. I think I can do that with complexity $\mathcal{O}(N)$, where I can create a matrix of $N\times N+1$ where the colomns represent the sorted values of the range, i.e., $\{0,1,2,...,N\}$, and the rows are the elements. 
So my questions are:

Is this correct?

Is there a better way to do that?

What if I changed the values of some of these numbers afterwards (after sorting), but all still comply with the initial rule, can I do better than linear sorting to maintain the order?

Comment: Are you saying you have all integers in the range 0..N?  Because if so, you can "sort" them in `O(1)`.

Comment: yes, not unique though. How $\mathcal{O}(1)$, sorry it is not my area, but do not we need at least to go over them and place them in order?

Comment: Oh I see now.  A matrix would work, but if you care about space efficiency then creating a vector with the count at each index works better.  If you don't require fast lookup, then a list of tuples (x, count(x)) is even more space efficient if you have many holes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a bound on your set of elements you can 
radix-sort them.

Formally let consider the following procedure:

```
    // Read the whole table and store the number of occurrences
    T <- Table[N] // Suppose initialized at 0
    for i = 0 to N do
        T[x[i]] <- T[x[i]]+1
    done
    // Unpack the elements
    c = 0
    for i = 0 to N do
        for j = 0 to T[i]-1 do
            x[c] <- i 
            c <- c+1
        done
    done
```

The soundness of the algorithm is evident. 
It's time complexity is in $\mathcal{O}(N)$ and its space 
complexity in $\mathcal{O}(N)$, estimated in arithmetic complexity (I mean by that the reading and writing complexities for your integers is independent of their bitsize).

The (bit) time complexity is in worst case a $\mathcal{O}(N\log N)$ since 
you might have to read $N+1$ bit strings of length $\Theta(log(N))$.

Notice that in any case, the algorithm is always **linear** in the size of its input.